# The mbstring extension is missing Windows AMPPS

Tags: php, windows, apache, web-services, ampps

I am running the AMPPS stack on Windows 10. I have been trying to get the configurations changed in php.ini while moving a Drupal site to my local environment. However, in the process I seem to have broken something. phppMyAdmin gives the following error:

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP
>   configuration.

When I check the php.ini, the extension is enabled:

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php-5.3\ext"

extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll

extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

What could be going wrong? Do I have a wrong extension directory selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `phpinfo()` for web and run `php -m` command for CLI if you don't see the extension in these pages then you should check the php.ini directory in the `phpinfo` page and alter that file.

This code in a e.g. phpinfo.php file will show you the php info page:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: When I check the directory using phpinfo(), I find that the settings in that file are exactly the same as what I pasted above. mbstring extension is enabled.

Comment: in the phpinfo page, do you see the mbstring info? I have something like this:

mbstring

Multibyte Support enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2

Comment: No. There is nothing showing up on "mbstring" search on that page. So, that means that it is enabled but not showing up.

Comment: do you have the `php_mbstring.dll` file in the extensions directory?

Comment: I am a bit confused on that. AMPPS comes with several versions of PHP. Is there a way to check which directory extensions are pulled from using phpinfo()?

Comment: yes in the same phpinfo page you should see `extension_dir`

Comment: Believe it or not, the thing just fixed itself. I did and changed nothing. No idea what was causing it :/

Comment: didn't you restart/log off your pc? in some cases you need to restart apache for the php extensions to take effect

Comment: I have done that several times but it would not help before.